# How to build Ember API docs for beta builds? Or access beta API docs online?

Tags: ember.js

I use Ember beta builds in my project and would like to use most recent API docs.
Also would be nice to be able to browse the docs when I am offline.

Is there any way I can build the API docs from the Ember github project?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using [YUIDoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/) to generate the documents from their sourcecode. So install that, checkout the ember sources from github and then run `yuidoc --server` from the commandline to get it hosted on `http://localhost:3000/`.